# behavior of matlab's rng() function in loop

Tags: matlab

With rng() before for loop Matlab generate one array of random number, within for loop another one. Both results are *repeatable*, so rng() seeds work. But I want to know the reason of such behavior.I was expecting the results to be same. I think actually it is not because of rng but for loop

Code exapmle?

```
for i = 1:2
rng(1,'philox');
disp(randn(2,1)); % 1st number is 0.0906, 2nd one is -0.7327
end


rng(1,'philox');
for i = 1:2
disp(randn(2,1)); % 1st number is 0.7565, 2nd one is -0.7096
end
```

Shouldn't the results be same? Isn't rng(1,..) storing same array of numbers for seed 1

Comment: Well, it could be for example that your code is wrong. You need a [mcve]. But likely, if you are doing `rng()` then you are not _setting_ the generator. You need to give it a value, e.g. `rng(1)`

Comment: @AnderBiguri, and you think my code did run just with run()?

Comment: Code that does not run is not the same that code that is wrong. For example, this code runs and computes the values wrong: `pi=5`. If this is not what you mean, sorry, I really not sure.

Comment: Sorry for being rude. by rng() I mean it as a function. Putting seed number in post does not change anything

Comment: Yes, but we can't help figure out why your code is not doing what its supposed to be doing without seeing a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, okay I am gonna put example. Thanks

Comment: Each of your calls to `randn` produced to numbers. When you say “second”, is it the second number of the first loop iteration, or the first number of the second loop iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as you expect and would describe, I believe. You are definitely not showing in your code example all the outputs. This is what I get when running it.

```
 >> test
    First case: 

    0.0906
   -0.7327

    0.0906
   -0.7327

    Second case:

    0.0906
   -0.7327

    0.7565
   -0.7096
```

In the first case, you reset the random number generator inside the loop, and there fore you get twice the same results (two numbers). In the second case, you only set it once, and therefore you get the same numbers as before, and then the second loop you get the next 2 corresponding random numbers produced by the algorithm. These algorithms, once started, will produce an infinite amount of different numbers, and they won't produce the same unless you explicitly call the restart of the algorithm with the seed, like you do in the first example.

All this is way less confusing if you call `disp(randn(1))` inside the loop, instead of generating 2 numbers each time.

Comment: Sorry , consider `disp(randn(1))` . But you are not answering my question. Why rng got reset in for loop? In seed #1 numbers series should be same

Comment: @Usingless ?? Look at the numbers! in the first code example, the number series is the same! It got reset because its inside the loop, calling `rng` resets it.